# Find Primefaces event supported by an p:ajax inside a component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there any way to get the events list supported by an `p:ajax` inside a component in Primefaces ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First you should see in [**Primefaces docs**](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html), for every component there is a "Ajax Behavior Events" section.

If you want to know from java code the list of events check the getEventNames() method.

From the [**docs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html) of ClientBehaviorHolder:

> **getEventNames()**: Returns a non-null, unmodifiable Collection
>   containing the names of the logical events supported by the component
>   implementing this interface.

For example, for InputText you have:

```
private static final Collection<String> EVENT_NAMES = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList("blur","change","valueChange","click","dblclick","focus","keydown","keypress","keyup","mousedown","mousemove","mouseout","mouseover","mouseup","select"));

public Collection<String> getEventNames() {
    return EVENT_NAMES;
}
```

The `EVENT_NAMES` collection is a list of all events supported by `InputText`. This method could be inherited from parent class, for `InputText` it's inherited from `javax.faces.component.HtmlInputText`.